# Get curl: (60) SSL certificate error with aws command

Tags: curl, ssl, amazon-s3

When I use `aws ls myBucket` or `aws mkdir newBucket` on my terminal to access my S3, I got:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.

If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I am not familiar with curl, how can fix this problem? My OS is OSX 10.9.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your bucket contain dots, e.g `com.example.mybucket`? Also I assume you use this [aws Perl client](http://timkay.com/aws/) by Tim Kay?

If yes then the problem is related to the fact that behind the scenes, this client performs [virtual-hosted-style requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html), e.g `GET https://com.example.mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/...`.

> **Note**: you can verify this as follow: `aws --curl-options="-v" ls com.example.mybucket 2>&1 | grep "About to connect"`

Such virtual-host style requests causes [certificate verification problem](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html).

So, I would greatly recommend you to use the official **[AWS Command Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)**. Using it is as simple as:

```
aws s3 ls com.example.mybucket
```

---

Alternatively, the poor-man solution is to turn off the certificate verification as detailed by curl, as follow:

```
aws --curl-options="-k" ls com.example.mybucket
```